# The command rbenv install is missing

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rbenv, ubuntu-10.04

In `Ubuntu 10.04` I just installed `rbenv`.
The install command is not present.

```
rbenv 0.4.0-49-g8b04303
Usage: rbenv <command> [<args>]

Some useful rbenv commands are:
   commands    List all available rbenv commands
   local       Set or show the local application-specific Ruby version
   global      Set or show the global Ruby version
   shell       Set or show the shell-specific Ruby version
   rehash      Rehash rbenv shims (run this after installing executables)
   version     Show the current Ruby version and its origin
   versions    List all Ruby versions available to rbenv
   which       Display the full path to an executable
   whence      List all Ruby versions that contain the given executable

See `rbenv help <command>' for information on a specific command.
For full documentation, see: https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#readme
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 299):

The `install` command is not embedded into rbenv, it comes from the [ruby-build](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build) plugin. You can install it using the command:

```
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git "$(rbenv root)"/plugins/ruby-build
```

On Mac OS X you can install it through homebrew:

```
brew install ruby-build
```

On [Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/Ruby#Selecting_the_default_Ruby_interpreter_on_a_per-user_basis_.28wheezy.29) (version >= 7) and Ubuntu (version >= 12.10) both rbenv and ruby-build can be installed using `apt-get` (or `aptitude`):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rbenv ruby-build
```

On FreeBSD ruby-build is available in the Ports Collection, it can be install both as a binary package or build from the port:

```
# Using pkgng rbenv will be installed
pkg install ruby-build

# Building ruby-build form Ports will install rbenv only if the RBENV option is set
cd /usr/ports/devel/ruby-build
make install
```

Comment: shouldn't `ruby-build` be a dependency of rbenv?

Comment: For OpenSUSE, this repo has rbenv: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/ruby:/extensions.

Comment: for mac this fixed the issue with me     brew install ruby-build

Comment: Yup. Exactly the same problem on Ubuntu 20.04 - this did the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 25):

I found that when using rbenv from a global directory, it's necessary to export the `RBENV_ROOT` variable, otherwise it won't load the plugins.

```
export RBENV_ROOT="/usr/local/rbenv"
if [ -d "${RBENV_ROOT}" ]; then
  export PATH="${RBENV_ROOT}/bin:${PATH}"
fi
```

Comment: This should be best answer

Comment: this is part of the post-install setup instructions as I recall

Comment: It works! It is also mentioned on the wiki: https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/wiki/Plugins

Answer (score 14):

As everyone mentioned problem is missing `ruby-build`. For older versions of OS `ruby-build` may not be available as an `apt` package. In that case install using [original instructions](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installation), which should've omitted the word `Optional` in this:

> 5. (Optional) Install ruby-build, which provides the rbenv install
>      command that simplifies the process of installing new Ruby versions.

```
git clone git@github.com:rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
# OR use http
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
```

Answer (score 12):

Simply install ruby-build in ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-build
```

And add

```
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

To your ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 8):

**Answered on 2021**

If you're getting that error, it's very likely you have accidentally skipped one of the installation instructions:

```
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL
```

*Replace `.bashrc` with whatever shell you're using, for example `.zshrc`, or just manually access your shell config file and paste this line:*

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"
```

---

I strong advise against re-installing/installing Ruby via `brew` or `apt-get` just to get around this issue. The whole point of using `rbenv` is to make your life easier in future when there is ruby version upgrade, or when you're working on different rails projects that require different version of ruby.

Answer (score 6):

I had installed the ruby-build plugin before and installed ruby 1.9.3-p327 using

```
$ rbenv install 1.9.3-p327
```

A few days later I tried to install ruby 2.0.0-p247 using

```
$ rbenv install 2.0.0-p247
```

but I received the error message

```
rbenv: no such command 'install'
```

All I had to do was to run

```
$ exec $SHELL -l
```

and that fixed the problem.

Comment: For anyone reading this in the future - I do recommend using `source` instead of `exec $SHELL`, unless you know what you're doing:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33048024/exec-shell-executes-from-ssh-wont-execute-in-playbook
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91095/what-does-exec-shell-l-do

Answer (score 5):

It looks like ruby-build is not present. Run this command :

```
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git "$(rbenv root)"/plugins/ruby-build
```

Answer (score 3):

Anyone finding their way here with this issue on OSX and already having installed ruby-build via homebrew (like me), you may solve this by just upgrading ruby-build:

```
brew update
brew upgrade ruby-build
```

This fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

This issue also happens in Linux when doing a stand-alone installation of ruby-build, if the `ruby-build` executable is not found in the path. If installing under `/usr/local`, try for example:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH /usr/local/bin/rbenv install ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I came to this solution, but looking for a macOS solution that uses MacPorts.
So, here the same command using MacPorts:

```
➜ ~ sudo port install ruby-build
Password:
--->  Computing dependencies for ruby-build
--->  Fetching archive for ruby-build
--->  Attempting to fetch ruby-build-20210804_0.darwin_19.noarch.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/ruby-build
--->  Attempting to fetch ruby-build-20210804_0.darwin_19.noarch.tbz2.rmd160 from https://packages.macports.org/ruby-build
--->  Installing ruby-build @20210804_0
--->  Activating ruby-build @20210804_0
--->  Cleaning ruby-build
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors
--->  No broken files found.
--->  No broken ports found.

➜ ~ curl -fsSL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/main/bin/rbenv-doctor | bash

Checking for `rbenv' in PATH: /opt/local/bin/rbenv
Checking for rbenv shims in PATH: OK
Checking `rbenv install' support: /opt/local/bin/rbenv-install (ruby-build 20210804)
Counting installed Ruby versions: none
  There aren't any Ruby versions installed under `/Users/user/.rbenv/versions'.
  You can install Ruby versions like so: rbenv install 3.0.2
Checking RubyGems settings: OK
Auditing installed plugins: OK
➜ ~ rbenv install 3.0.2
Downloading openssl-1.1.1k.tar.gz...
-> https://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/892a0875b9872acd04a9fde79b1f943075d5ea162415de3047c327df33fbaee5
Installing openssl-1.1.1k...
```