# rbenv: no such command "install" even though ruby-build is installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rbenv

I'm trying to get ruby 2.1.4 installed via rbenv for a client project.

Though previously I've been able to install ruby versions through rbenv, after upgrading to Yosemite, I keep getting the following error:

```
rbenv: no such command 'install'
```

After digging around, I saw lots of tips about how "install" comes from the ruby-build plugin, which is installed via homebrew:

```
which ruby-build
/usr/local/bin/ruby-build
```

I installed rbenv via Homebrew, but when I try use which rbenv, I get:

```
rbenv () {
typeset command
command="$1" 
if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]
then
    shift
fi
case "$command" in
    (rehash|shell) eval `rbenv "sh-$command" "$@"` ;;
    (*) command rbenv "$command" "$@" ;;
esac
}
```

I have run brew update and brew upgrade rbenv ruby-builder, and it tells me everything is up to date.

Below is my full $PATH:

zsh: no such file or directory: /usr/local/var/rbenv/shims:/usr/local/var/rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/dannycox/.rbenv/shims:/Users/dannycox/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Users/dannycox/.rbenv/shims:/Users/dannycox/.rbenv/bin

UPDATE: Found another answer with a little deeper digging on github that showed signs of promise, but failed to solve the issue with rbenv. https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/issues/610#issuecomment-56240018

I believe 2.1.4 is now installed on my machine, but it installed here: 
    Successfully installed ruby 2.1.4 into /Users/dannycox/.rubies/ruby-2.1.4

As a result, my bundler won't work with the new ruby 2.0 version and I get the following error when I try to gem install bundle:

```
Fetching: bundler-1.7.6.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory
```

Still need help to identify why ruby-build isn't playing nice with rbenv...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618113/the-command-rbenv-install-is-missing

Comment: Thanks Nikola - unfortunately as I said in my original question, I currently have ruby-build installed and am still getting the same "no such command as 'install'"

Comment: hey @Danny did you get any fix for this issue? I'm facing the exactly same issue. Just upgraded to Yosemite.

Comment: you need to run `install.sh` from ruby-build

Comment: Fixed with: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24249090/1505348

Answer (score 50):

Make sure to install optional step 5 in the instructions:

```
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
```

Install ruby-build, which provides the rbenv install command that simplifies the process of installing new Ruby versions.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Alberto. I had first installed ruby-build using apt, which had placed it into `/usr/bin/ruby-build` and somehow (I didn't troubleshoot successfully) was not visible to `~./rbenv`. Installing via github into `~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build` was the trick.

To spell out the last steps for any novices in a hurry, after running Alberto's `git clone` command: use `~./rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/install.sh` If it fails to execute, use sudo. Check success with `rbenv install -l`

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, and trace the problem to ruby-build. So i updated the homebrew and reinstall the ruby-build

```
> brew update
> brew reinstall ruby-build
```

Find the ruby version

```
> brew ls -v ruby-build | grep 2.1.4
```

then install intended version ruby again

```
> rbenv install 2.1.4
```

Answer (score 0):

From your perms error I think you are trying to install to the system ruby, which is the one that comes with Apple OSX. You want to use rbenv to install your own ruby and install gems into that.

Read -  https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build#readme

And use the

```
rbenv versions
```

command to show what instance of ruby you are about to install the gems into. If it's **system** then you need to install your own ruby instance and then use that ruby for gems.