# Chef + rbenv: "rbenv: no such command 'install'" despite ruby-build being installed

Tags: ruby, bash, chef-infra, rbenv

I am learning Chef and building a cookbook with recipes for installing `rbenv` and `ruby-build`. The `ruby-build` recipe installs the program and then attempts to install Ruby 2.3.1 with `rbenv`. However, every time I run `chef-client` to converge, this last step fails with the error `rbenv: no such command 'install'` *even though* the installation of `ruby-build` finishes successfully.

```
bash "initialize rbenv and install ruby 2.3.1" do
  user "david"
  cwd  node["user"]["home"]
  environment({
    "PATH" => "#{node['rbenv']['bin']}:#{node['rbenv']['root']}/shims:#{ENV['PATH']}"
  })

  # code "eval \"$(rbenv init -)\" && rbenv install 2.3.1"
  code <<-EOF
  eval "$(rbenv init -)"
  rbenv install 2.3.1
  EOF
end
```

I've commented out the one-line way that I also tried. In both cases it says that `install` is missing despite the program being there.

In fact, I can go into the machine manually and run these commands just fine:

```
[root@myserver ~]# su david
[david@myserver root]$ cd
[david@myserver ~]$ eval "$(.rbenv/bin/rbenv init -)"
[david@myserver ~]$ .rbenv/bin/rbenv install 2.3.1
Downloading ruby-2.3.1.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.3/ruby-2.3.1.tar.bz2
```

Any ideas why this would be failing during convergence but not at the command line??

Comment: Could this have something to do with it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24249090/823617

Comment: I don't think so because I'm not using a global rbenv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `$HOME` in shell environment:

```
environment({
    "PATH" => "#{node['rbenv']['bin']}:#{node['rbenv']['root']}/shims:#{ENV['PATH']}",
    "HOME" => node["user"]["home"],
  })
```

Comment: that seems to have fixed it! any chance you could explain what's going on? when I log into the server manually as user `david` it seems that `$HOME` is already set

Comment: Yeah, it's a side effect of how Chef (really Mixlib ShellOut) runs a subcommand as a different user. Normally `$HOME` is set by your login shell when you connect via SSH or a TTY, but when Chef runs a command it doesn't do this. We've debating just having Chef always set this variable but for now it doesn't.